# How to Insert records into mongo with Node where records have an $oid

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm new to mongo and node and i'm trying to create a script that essentially works similar to rails `rake db:seed` task where I have a set of .json files in a specific folder, and when I run `$ node seed` it will run my seed.js file which takes all of those .json files and inserts the contents into their appropriate mongo collections based on the filename of the .json file.

Essentially I run `$ node seed` and it executes `/seed.js` which looks at `/seeds/account.json`, /`seeds/customer.json`, etc.

This way I can commit this code and then next developer can just run `$ node seed` and his mongo instance will be populated with some data to work with.

The problem i'm having is that the data that I got is from a dump of my collections in mongo so some sample data for account looks like this:

```
{ _id: { '$oid': '534d832177da4e0d38000001' },
  id: 1,
  name: something,
  dateTime: '2014-04-15T14:06:09-05:00' }
```

Now when I run `$ node seed`, I get this error:

```
[Error: key $oid must not start with '$']
```

Is there any way to get around this error or am I going to have to remove all the `$oid`'s from all my .json files?

seed.js:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/testdb');
var dir = './seeds';
var db = mongoose.connection;

// Show connection error if there is one
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'Database Connection Error:'));

// If we successfully connected to mongo
db.once('open', function callback() {

    var fs = require('fs'); // Used to get all the files in a directory

    // Read all the files in the folder
    fs.readdir(dir, function(err, list) {

        // Log the error if something went wrong
        if(err) {
            console.log('Error: '+err);
        }

        // For every file in the list
        list.forEach(function(file) {

            // Set the filename without the extension to the variable collection_name
            var collection_name = file.split(".")[0];
            var parsedJSON = require(dir + '/' + file);

            for(var i = 0; i < parsedJSON.length; i++) {

                // Counts the number of records in the collection
                db.collection('cohort').count(function(err, count) {
                    if(err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                });

                db.collection(collection_name).insert(parsedJSON[i], function(err, records) {

                    if(err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    }

                    console.log(records[0]);
                    console.log("Record added as "+records[0]);

                });
            }

        });
    });
});
```

Or is there any libraries out there that already exist for this kind of task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#field-names

The field names cannot start with the dollar sign ($) character.

Part of the mongodb spec as it uses $ to indicate operations like $inc or $unset.

Answer (score 3):

So there is a thing called the [extended JSON syntax](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/) which is more of a spec and while supported by some driver implementations is yet to be implemented in the node native driver itself.

While there is one implementation I know of to work with converting these types, in the [jsontomongo](https://www.npmjs.org/package/json2mongo) module for node, all of the types are not strictly supported. Yet as can clearly be seen [in the code](https://github.com/watson/json2mongo/blob/master/index.js):

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function (query) {
  var key, val;
  for (key in query) {
    if (!query.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;
    val = query[key];
    switch (key) {
    case '$date':
      return new Date(val);
    case '$regex':
      return new RegExp(val, query.$options);
    case '$undefined':
      return undefined;
    }
    if (typeof val === 'object')
      query[key] = module.exports(val);
  }
  return query;
};
```

Implementing the full specification or just the things you need such as `ObjectId` would be a fairly trivial exercise. You might even want to contribute your work as a node module yourself.

So that is essentially the sort of code you need to parse the object structure that results from parsing the JSON string.

Answer (score 2):

Use this instead of $oid:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5063114bd386d8fadbd6b004")}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `mongodb-extended-json` npm extension: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb-extended-json

Here is the usage example taken from documentation:

```js
var EJSON = require('mongodb-extended-json');
var BSON = require('bson');

var doc = {
  _id: BSON.ObjectID(),
  last_seen_at: new Date(),
  display_name: undefined
};

console.log('Doc', doc);
// > Doc { _id: 53c2ab5e4291b17b666d742a, last_seen_at: Sun Jul 13 2014 11:53:02 GMT-0400 (EDT), display_name: undefined }

console.log('JSON', JSON.stringify(doc));
// > JSON {"_id":"53c2ab5e4291b17b666d742a","last_seen_at":"2014-07-13T15:53:02.008Z"}

console.log('EJSON', EJSON.stringify(doc));
// > EJSON {"_id":{"$oid":"53c2ab5e4291b17b666d742a"},"last_seen_at":{"$date":1405266782008},"display_name":{"$undefined":true}}

// And likewise, EJSON.parse works just as you would expect.
EJSON.parse('{"_id":{"$oid":"53c2ab5e4291b17b666d742a"},"last_seen_at":{"$date":1405266782008},"display_name":{"$undefined":true}}');
// { _id: 53c2ab5e4291b17b666d742a,
//   last_seen_at: Sun Jul 13 2014 11:53:02 GMT-0400 (EDT),
```