# Joi schema validation "key $oid must not start with '$' "

Tags: javascript, mongodb, hapi.js, joi

I'm using Hapi/Joi to validate my schema and I'm having problems to understand what i need to do to validate the two id's (`cliente_id` and `id` inside Step2) that i have in my array of objects:

**My json**

```
{
    "DI":
    {
        "Step2": [
        {
            "id":
            {
                "$oid": "5f077925ac7e9319ff7d1c6b"
            },
            "produto": "cafeteira",
            "ncm": "9878.7389",
            "descricao": "cafeteira capsula",
            "cliente_id":
            {
                "$oid": "5f0775e8ac7e9319ff7d1c68"
            },
            "aliqII": 0.2,
            "aliqIpi": 0,
            "aliqPis": 0.21,
            "aliqCofins": 0.0965,
            "pesoUnitario": 0.43,
            "unitario": 0.78,
            "dumping": 0,
            "cubagemUnitario": 0,
            "quantidade": "23",
            "icmEstadoDestino": 0,
            "mvaAjustado": 0,
            "markup": 0.12,
            "selected": "true",
            "url": "http://localhost:3000/produtos/5f077925ac7e9319ff7d1c6b.json"
        }]
    }
}
```

**My Joi validation in my API:**

```
const valoresStep2 = Joi.object({
    id:  Joi.any(),
    cliente_id: Joi.any(),
    selected: Joi.boolean().required(),
    produto: Joi.string().trim().required(),
    ncm: Joi.string().trim().required(),
    aliqII: Joi.number().required(),
    aliqIpi: Joi.number().required(),
    aliqPis: Joi.number().required(),
    aliqCofins: Joi.number().required(),
    descricao: Joi.string().trim().required(),
    pesoUnitario: Joi.number().required(),
    unitario: Joi.number().required(),
    dumping: Joi.number().required(),
    cubagemUnitario: Joi.number().required(),
    quantidade: Joi.number().required(),
    icmEstadoDestino: Joi.number().required(),
    mvaAjustado: Joi.number().required(),
    markup: Joi.number().required(),
    url: Joi.string().trim()
}).unknown();
```

**the Error:**

```
 "message": "key $oid must not start with '$'",
  "stack": "Error: key $oid must not start with '$'
```

I'm tried to use the [`any()`](https://github.com/sideway/joi/blob/master/API.md#objectunknownallow) to validate and I tried to use the package in npm [joi-objectid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/joi-objectid) but anything works.

Comment: Is it definitely Joi that's erroring? It validates fine when I try.

Comment: @Ankh it's seems to be, but what do you think? the error persist here

Comment: I don't think you're reading the error stack correctly. Your error matches this problem almost exactly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23206099/how-to-insert-records-into-mongo-with-node-where-records-have-an-oid

Comment: @Cehhiro I will try to solve this with this link and i post here what i did